# PHP mysql session array

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a little question.

I have few stored values in session Array. These values are ID's of products.
After that i want to display products from my database, but this is not working propertly for me.
Can someone help me a little? :) (I am still learning :) )

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbconnect.php';
$orderid = $_SESSION['order'];
foreach ($orderid as $value) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID LIKE '%$value%'";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["tag"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["price"].',- Kč</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="product.php?id='.$row["productID"].'"><img src="images/'.$row["tag"].'.jpg" width=70"></a></td>';
        echo '<td>1</td>'   ;
        echo '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">X</a></td>';
    }
}
?>
```

var_dump($orderid); shows:

```
array(1) {
    ["order"]=> array(10) {
        [0]=> string(2) "44"
        [1]=> string(2) "46"
        [2]=> string(2) "44"
        [3]=> string(2) "54"
        [4]=> string(1) "1"
        [5]=> string(2) "44"
        [6]=> string(1) "1"
        [7]=> string(2) "44"
        [8]=> string(2) "47"
        [9]=> string(2) "74"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working propertly for me" ?

Comment: add the error message(s) you get.We cannot debug this for you without more information on what went wrong

Comment: i don't see session_start()

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `<table>` tag surrounding `<tr>`?

Comment: The list of products is not right , I want to display products, which has specific id.

Comment: Session_start() is above on the top of all this code :) This is something like shopping cart, I have stored values in session (that works) now i want to display products from database by ID's :)

Comment: What does `var_dump($orderid);` show after retrieving it from the session show?

Comment: I have <table> above this code, everything works correctly except displaying products

Comment: When I echo result of this array() , ill get ID's of products (array of ID's)

Comment: var_dump($orderid); shows: array(1) {
  ["order"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "44"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "46"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "44"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "54"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "44"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "44"
    [8]=>
    string(2) "47"
    [9]=>
    string(2) "74"
  }
}

Comment: Looks like you need to do another foreach, since `$orderid` is an array of arrays.

Comment: In $sql query instead of using `LIKE '%$value%'";` try this: `LIKE '". $value ."'";`

Comment: OHHH thanks Studocwho :) thats it!! :) thanks alot :)

Comment: why searching complicated when it's simple ? x) @Studocwho then you just have to make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just for the purposes of SO, I'll make my comment as an answer:

In the $sql query instead of using `LIKE '%$value%'";` use this: `LIKE '". $value ."'";`

This ensures that we actually get the value of the variable.

Comment: This is a massive security bug [waiting to happen](https://xkcd.com/327/). The only way to securely inject user data into a SQL queries is [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/23118).